# Problem with pip3 (bad interpreter: No such file or directory)

Tags: pip, python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04

I use Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and python3.6 but before that, I had 3.7 but I uninstalled it.
now when I try to use pip3 I received this error:

p4@p4-VirtualBox:~$ pip3 --version

-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip3: /usr/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

In additional:

which python3.6

/usr/bin/python3.6

Thank you in advance.